# Update API specs in different business groups

Tags: mule4, raml, anypoint-platform, oas

In Anypoint Platform we have two business groups org1 and org2. In org1 group, I have updated the existing RAML API specification and same changes should be apply to org2 group API spec as well. Like this I have to update lot of applications. Is there any best method to update changes in one group to other?

Any tool suggest or any options in Anypoint Platform itself?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have updated RAML files and you need to apply those changes to your Mule applications that are deployed in different business groups in Anypoint Platform.

Short answer: No, there is no existing tool to do that.

Long answer: updating files in your applications is done outside Anypoint Platform, for example in the IDE (Anypoint Studio) or whatever editor or development tools you have. In Anypoint Platform you use Runtime Manager to deploy updated applications. Runtime Manager doesn't has features to update files or any other changes inside your applications. This is a separation of concerns. Also Business Groups in Anypoint Platform are independent of each other. Each application deployed in Anypoint Platform is also independent of other deployments, even if the use the deployable file. So there is no way to say to Runtime Manager update this application file in all applications that use it. Having said that, you could probably use Anypoint Platform REST APIs and tools (like Anypoint CLI) to create your own tool to automate this kind of update, totally or partly, like when implementing a CI/CD deployment pipeline.